# CSS line-break ONLY not in IE?

Tags: html, css

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wG9vu/1/

To summarize, I have a fixed-width div with several `<p> and <img>` tags inside.  The length of those tags are based on generated input.  All of them work exactly as expected except at the VERY bottom of the page on the left is the "Star and Rhinestone" charm.  That charm renders perfectly on IE, as shown here:

[image: IE working perfectly]

But on chrome, firefox, opera, and safari, we get this:
[image: Others, not so much]

The html for the relevant div looks like this:

```
<div class="charm_thumbnail">
<img src="http://www.ddbeadworks.com/static/media/images/charms/CMSsv006.jpg" alt="Star and Rhinestone" />
<p class="charm_list_name">Star and Rhinestone</p>
<p class="charm_list_desc">Silver-tone 1/4&quot;</p>
<p id="charm_list_price">$5.00</p>
<form method="post" action="." class="cart">
<div>
    <blah blah crap related to the add to cart button>                          
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

The title (charm_list_name) is alotted one line in the layout, and the decription is alotted two lines.  IE displays correctly: the title fits on one line, and even though the description is only one line, the space is properly resereved.

In chrome and others, the title goes down on to two lines, thus the reserved space for the description stays, and the end result is pushing the add to cart button out of the box.

I have tried some browser reset css to no avail: the title STILL went on to two lines in everything but IE.

As you can see, the "Star and Rhinestone" title fills, in IE, the available space COMPLETELY, without a pixel to spare.  I noticed `-webkit-margin-before: 1em; -webkit-margin-after: 1em;` thinking I had found the problem, but no such luck.  I set them both to 0px, but nothing happened.

Any ideas how I can make IE and ALL the other browsers display the same width?  Where am I losing pixels?

Here is the relevant css:

```
html {
     font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 12px;
}

div.charm_thumbnail {
text-align:center;
float:left;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
border-color: #b78e18;
padding: 3px;
margin: 7px 4px;
height: 210px;
width: 120px;
 }
.charm_sold_out {
    position: absolute;
    background: #841075;
    color: white;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 6px;
    padding: 4px 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.charm_thumbnail > img {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.charm_thumbnail > p {
    max-width: 114px;
}
.charm_thumbnail > .charm_list_name {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 0px 3px;
}
.charm_thumbnail > .charm_list_desc {
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 11px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0px 3px;
}

.charm_thumbnail > #charm_list_price {
    text-align: left;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #b78e18;
    margin: 0px 3px;
}

#add_charm_to_cart {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

**Important Edit:**  I included my html css line because I'm thinking it has to do with font-scaling on different browsers.  Anyone have any knowledge if that would cause something like this? Rounding up instead of down sort of thing because of `100%/1.4`?

NOTE: In the fiddle, I'm not reproducing the full error, but that doesn't matter.  What matters is that, in chrome and others, the title is running onto two lines, which is the problem.

Comment: You need to post your CSS since your problem is there. With the data you provided I cannot reproduce your bug. http://jsfiddle.net/wG9vu/

Comment: "The title is alotted one line" is not a technical term. There is nothing that prevents the title from taking up more space other than the editor's vigilance to keep titles short. So, before anything else, you need to answer this question: *what do you want to happen if a title does not fit inside a single line*?

Comment: Can’t reproduce your problem in Opera, but anyway, [you still got some work to do …](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.ddbeadworks.com/category/charms/)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  You're right, I didn't code a limit to the one-line title.  But the editors KNOW the tittle should fit on one line. They use IE, so they thought it was fine.  The problem is, they didn't look at the other browsers, and they shouldn't have to.  So to answer your question, if the title goes on to two lines because of length, I don't care at all - I care that it either DOES or DOESN'T go on to two lines CONSISTENTLY on all browsers.

Comment: Not reproducible on Chrome and Firefox. And why would it matter that the rendering is consistent? Few visitors will whine about such differences in rendering. What matters is whether the rendering is ugly or not. There is no reasonably identified problem to be addressed. You should not expect others to do basic debugging of your code.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela It matters because my editors use one browser to check for ugliness, and it is only ugly on other browsers.  As I mentioned, it IS ugly, and both visitors AND the client would notice, as you would have seen if you looked at the pictures.  The reasonable problem to be addressed is: why on earth is this rendering differently on different browsers?  Also, you may have noticed this is a community site about helping others who are stuck on coding problems.  When I have spent an hour and half looking, it goes beyond "basic debugging" and into "problem with potential community value."

Comment: @CBroe Strange that my Opera and yours render it differently, too.  And anyways, yes I am in the "week of debugging and finalizing," so I have quite a bit of work ahead of me! =P

Comment: Basic debugging includes producing code, preferably minimal code, that actually reproduces the issue. Even with the CSS code now added, the problem does not arise. You should include a fiddle link that lets others to see the problem in action without trying (in vain) to reconstruct what you really have.

Comment: Here is a link to an updated fiddle, in which I just copy and pasted the CSS I provided into the fiddle Rafael put together, probably in about 10 seconds.  The problem appears just as well in the fiddle as it does on the site, which is an even bigger mystery if you and other aren't seeing that. http://jsfiddle.net/wG9vu/1/ edit: I linked the wrong fiddle

Comment: Is the problem solved now? If so, you should post the solution an an answer yourself. Otherwise, in your screen shots, the fonts are bigger in the bottom one. Not by much, but still... Are you sure you're using the same settings in all the browsers? Zoom level, DPI, compatibility settings, allow websites to specify fonts etc. Also, what happens if you replace `font:100%/1.4 .. font-size:12px` by `font:12px/1.4 ..`? And the question that hasn't been asked, which IE version?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `white-space: nowrap;` to your `.charm_list_name` class:

```
.charm_list_name {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin: 0px 0px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: This "worked" in that it caused the title to come to one line in chrome, but it does so by pushing right through the border by a pixel, which is equally inconsistent across browsers.  A good start though, thanks!